# Temporarily make entire site unavailable on user visit

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a weird thing I'm trying to achieve.

What I would like is when a user visits a certain HTML page, a whole set of pages are made temporarily unavailable for all users, for a fixed time (like 20 minutes). After that the pages should be accessible again. Also possible is a temporary redirect or censoring of the pages.

Why? I want to give users a penalty for entering a forbidden area in a GPS based game that displays certain webpages based on the users GPS data. That last part is working fine.

After searching I thought that it might work with PHP, but I have minimal experience with that. I know HTML and CSS, and how to read and modify existing JavaScript and PHP scripts, not really how to build those codes from scratch.

Another option (that I can't really figure out) was to make the site send an e-mail when someone enters the page, and make another service like ["If This Then That"](https://ifttt.com) take the site offline/change file names.

Comment: In order to do the thing you want to do, you need some sort of persistent data storage - a database or some such.  Also, I'm guessing that this is some sort of strongly cooperate-and-organize game?  Otherwise, punishing everyone for the actions of one person is probably not what you want to do.  Likewise, unless you have them all meeting in person or otherwise building bonds of loyalty, I'd be worried that someone would just trigger the "no one gets in" effect more or less constantly for the troll factor.

Comment: True, it's a cooperative game. It is for teenagers though, so they might still troll eachother.

Answer (score 1):

On your PHP page, I would make something like this:

```
<?php
   if(!can_view_page()){
       header('Location: other_page.php');
   }
?>
```

In the `can_view_page()` function you need to check whether or not the conditions are met (e.g. in right location to view page).

Comment: Fear not the capital letter ;)

Comment: thanks, looks like the same general idea as the other answer. It helps me, but I´m not experienced enough with PHP to make this work. I´ll look for a programmer.

Answer (score 1):

Like the other answerer suggested, create a function that you can use to check conditions for whether the user can visit the page or not. Here's some pseudocode that uses a mix of php, python and javascript syntax haha :)

```
function isAllowedViewing(is_good) {
    if (is_good):
        if "/var/www/mysite/disable_visits" file exists:
            contents = (read contents)
            # If 20 minutes has elapsed since first being disabled
            if (now.toEpoch() - contents.toEpoch()) > 1200:
                remove file from file system
            else:
                header("Location: thats_bad.php")
    else:
        if "/var/www/mysite/disable_visits" file does not exist:
            create the file on the file system and write now.toEpoch() to it
        # Optional:
        else:
            re-write the current time to the file to reset the 20 minute counter (for every time the user re-visits the bad page)
}
```

So to use it, you would call the function at the top of every page. If the page is a normal page that you allow normal access to, pass `true` to the function. If you want to punish the user for visiting the page, pass `false`.

Comment: My head hurts after reading that code :S But +1, you managed to convey the general idea! I take it we are not a fan of copy pasta ;)

Comment: @Lix Haha my head hurts after trying to convey it without actual PHP code. I've used PHP before, but didn't want to take the time to get all the code exact

Comment: Thanks! Looks like I have to find a programmer to help me with this stuff. I get the general idea, but finding out the exact code would take me days...